# Accept AMD EULA for custom resolution with keyboard only

Tags: windows-10, resolution, amd-ryzen

Currently I have 640x480 in Windows 10 with Ryzen 3 2200G and Acer AL1916W and I want to change the resolution to 1440x900. The Windows screen driver does not support anything else than 640x480 except in safe mode with 1024x768 so I wanted to give it a try with the AMD software using a custom resolution. My main problem that I cannot scroll the EULA text and accept it to change resolution because the software is not compatible with 640x480. Is there any way to do it with keyboard only without seeing it? Can somebody try it out? I tried with space and enter, but no success... ;-(

Comment: Any up-to-date Windows 10 should natively support all resolutions available with the Vega graphics. This is the first time I see someone reporting this.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The problem is with the screen I think https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/acer-al1916w-resolution-problems.15171/ But I have no idea how to fix it except adding a custom resolution. Though the color depth will be still bad. :S

Comment: A forum thread from 2006 and Windows XP is likely irrelevant for Windows 10 in 2024. And in any case the users there mentioned a driver from Acer, the monitor's manufacturer. It's rare but happens. Typically monitors don't need any user installable drivers but there are exceptions depending on the connection type - digital ones shouldn't need it, at all, but analogue like VGA might.

Comment: @harrymc It's mentioned in the question: Acer AL1916W

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tried to look for a screen driver, but Acer no longer supports this screen. What I find really strange that with an old computer it works with 1440x900 resolution. I am not sure how or why. Isn't there a way to copy the screen driver from there?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have found the INF file content here: https://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/8246-cant-get-native-resolution.html The only problem that it is text and I cannot install it without signature. Really this starts to be very annoying. I'll start the old computer and check what kind of INF file it has for the screen, maybe I will be lucky. Another thing I can try is using its graphics card, which would be a shame when I have a Vega 8 integrated. Next month I'll buy a screen if I cannot solve this.

Comment: Your monitor has no driver to download. You could try to create custom resolution using [Custom Resolution Utility](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks! I'll try.

Comment: @harrymc https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/c92e4255a897d6d97295724e5934a5315238a63bb8e0b8b320c5f9b21eb0f531 Is this false positive?

Comment: Seems so. This software is from 2021 and has been used a lot (including by me). I don't believe it's infected. All the other antivirus products gave it a clean bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @harrymc suggested, I used CRU instead of the AMD utility. The CRU was compatible with 640x480 resolution, so it was very easy to add a few custom resolutions. https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU

Comment: Now you can install the driver/software from AMD.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I could, but CRU solved the original problem I needed it for. :-)